# Control the scroll speed of div while page scrolls

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, parallax

I want to decrease the scroll speed of a div (with class caption) with height 400px and width 500px while the user scrolls the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            $(caption)...
        });
```

I tried with jquery animate on window scroll but didn't get it working.

IS there a way I can make this happen

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate() function of Jquery like this :

> **$('html, body')**.animate({
>                           scrollTop: 300,
>                           scrollLeft: 0
>                       }, **1000**);

1000 (1 second ) represents the time it takes to appear.

Comment: actually, the div shld always be present - the user shld see it - the only thing is, it shld move slower than the body